# Differentiating Function of Multiple Variables

Tags: partial-derivative, parametric

Consider a function $w=f(x,y)$, where $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$. Verify each of the following:

$$
\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}} = 
\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{r}}\cos\theta - 
\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{\theta}}\frac{\sin\theta}{r}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{y}} = 
\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{r}}\sin\theta +
\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{\theta}}\frac{\cos\theta}{r}
$$

$$
\left(\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2 +
\left(\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{y}}\right)^2 =
\left(\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{r}}\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{\theta}}\right)^2
$$

I believe I am supposed to utilize the chain rule:

$$
Z = f(x(t), y(t))
$$
$$
\frac{\partial{Z}}{\partial{t}} = 
\frac{\partial{Z}}{\partial{x}}
\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}} + 
\frac{\partial{Z}}{\partial{y}}
\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{t}},
$$

but I am unsure how to modify the formula to obtain $\frac{\partial{Z}}{\partial{x}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain rule, write
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \\
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} 
 \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
   \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} &  \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \\
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} 
 \end{bmatrix} =: \mathbf{J} \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \\
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} 
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Compute $\mathbf{J}$:
$$
  \mathbf{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
   -r\sin\theta &  r\cos\theta
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Find the inverse of $\mathbf{J}$ (which does not exist at $r = 0$):
$$
  \mathbf{J}^{-1} = \frac{1}{r}\begin{bmatrix}
   r\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
   r\sin\theta &  \cos\theta
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \\
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} 
 \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{J}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} \\
   \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} 
 \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{r} \begin{bmatrix} 
   r\cos\theta \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} - \sin\theta \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} \\
   r\sin\theta \frac{\partial w}{\partial r} + \cos\theta \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta}
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The expressions you need follow directly.